# Cannot capture video data on Swift Playgrounds, captureOutput AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate delegate method not called

Tags: swift, camera, swift-playground

I want to get access to the iPad's camera on the Swift Playgrounds iPad app. I have found that it's not possibile to capture video data, even though my playground runs ok.

`captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)`, a delegate method of the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol, is not getting called (probably because no video data is coming in), while it is in my iOS app.

The view in my playground is supposed to display the FaceTime camera view. Why can't I display the camera output even though [Apple explicitly says it's allowed to do so](https://developer.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/)? Also, the Playground app asks me for camera permissions as soon as I open my playground, so it should be allowed in some way.

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage
import AVFoundation
import ImageIO
import PlaygroundSupport

class Visage: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    var visageCameraView : UIView = UIView()
    fileprivate var faceDetector : CIDetector?
    fileprivate var videoDataOutput : AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
    fileprivate var videoDataOutputQueue : DispatchQueue?
    fileprivate var cameraPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    fileprivate var captureSession : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    fileprivate let notificationCenter : NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.captureSetup(AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)
        var faceDetectorOptions : [String : AnyObject]?
        faceDetectorOptions = [CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh as AnyObject]
        self.faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: faceDetectorOptions)
    }

    func beginFaceDetection() {
        self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func endFaceDetection() {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    }

    fileprivate func captureSetup (_ position : AVCaptureDevicePosition) {
        var captureError : NSError?
        var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!

        for testedDevice in AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){
            if ((testedDevice as AnyObject).position == position) {
                captureDevice = testedDevice as! AVCaptureDevice
            }
        }

        if (captureDevice == nil) {
            captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        }

        var deviceInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput?
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            captureError = error
            deviceInput = nil
        }
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        if (captureError == nil) {
            if (captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput)) {
                captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
            }

            self.videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            self.videoDataOutput!.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
            self.videoDataOutput!.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            self.videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue", attributes: [])
            self.videoDataOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.videoDataOutputQueue!)

            if (captureSession.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput)) {
                captureSession.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
            }
        }

        visageCameraView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer?.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        visageCameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
    }

    // NOT CALLED
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {            
        print("delegate method called!")
    }
}

class SmileView: UIView {
    let smileView = UIView()
    var smileRec: Visage!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(smileView)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        smileRec = Visage()
        smileRec.beginFaceDetection()
        let cameraView = smileRec.visageCameraView
        self.addSubview(cameraView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
let sView = SmileView(frame: frame)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sView
```

Comment: I run into the exact same problem, have you figured out a solution? Not even the preview layer displays a video feed.

Comment: @knl I haven't yet found a solution, but I will update this question as soon as I get it to work!

Comment: @Cesare I'm stuck too :(, I will post a solution too if I get it to work.

Comment: This looks most definetely to be a bug @Harish

Comment: @Cesare this is looking more and more like a bug except I highly doubt a bug report is gonna fix it in time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: this should have been fixed :)

--

Edit: this was confirmed to be a bug by Apple.

I have filed a bug report and I will update this answer when new official information comes in.

Comment: Did you file the bug report? Also, just a quick question, were any workarounds suggested?

Comment: Yes, I filed a bug report and unfortunately I haven't found any workaround for this issue :/

Comment: Oh well , hopefully that bug is fixed soon lol! We don't have much time haha, just a suggestion for your project.. it might be possible to just provide an example image for now and then in the essay explain what you would've done if the camera were working.

Comment: No problem ! I'll probably do that and hope they fix it in time haha.

Comment: Also do you have the radar number? I might include that in my essay.

Comment: Sorry @Harish, people's bugs are internal to Apple only so I don't feel comfortable sharing the number with you/having my bug report associated with your submission. However, I will update you when Apple gets back to me. It's not likely at all that it will be fixed by the WWDC Scholarship deadline (https://openradar.appspot.com/26909140 this radar has been posted almost a year ago)

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I didn't know that it's internal and that is totally fine! And yeah sounds good , lemme know when they give you an update

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the `needsIndefiniteExecution` property so that execution is not stopped after your code is completed. From apple:

> By default, all top-level code is executed, and then execution is
>   terminated. When working with asynchronous code, enable indefinite
>   execution to allow execution to continue after the end of the
>   playground’s top-level code is reached. This, in turn, gives threads
>   and callbacks time to execute.
>
> Editing the playground automatically stops execution, even when
>   indefinite execution is enabled.
>
> Set needsIndefiniteExecution to true to continue execution after the
>   end of top-level code. set it to false to stop execution at that
>   point.

So possible code at the end will be :

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
let sView = SmileView(frame: frame)
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sView
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to my question. Unfortunately, setting the `needsIndefiniteExecution` property to `true` did not change anything at all.